# forms (devdemon) and redirects

Tags: templates, forms, devdemon

I am redirecting a user to a custom template after they submit a form.
I'd like to include their name on the thank you page, but as it's a redirect, I can't get any form data.

I tried editing this line on mod.forms.php

```
$form['return'] = $form['form_settings']['return_url'];
```

To

```
$form['return'] = '/mytmeplategroup/thankyou/' . ee()->input->post('name_first');
```

But as the return URL is generated BEFORE the form is submitted, this is clearly the wrong answer.

Can I pass custom variables to a new template (worst case, just a form submission entry Id and I can go get the data perhaps?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use use a variable in your return url like this:

return="/mytmeplategroup/thankyou/%FENTRY_ID%/"

And on the thankyou template do something like this:

{exp:forms:entries fentry_id="{segment_3}"}

Answer (score 1):

I dunno what Forms is doing with `return_url`, but could you do something with JavaScript in the generated form's `onsubmit` event?

Comment: Need a non JS solution sadly.. I ended up 'hacking' the module.. added a hidden field on the form page too.. using that to set a session and pick up the data elsewhere... phew!